# What's the best way of converting a numeric array in a text file to a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

So I'm trying to create an array from a text file, the text file is laid out as follows. The numbers in the first two columns both go to 165:

```
0   0    1.0 0.0
1   0    0.0 0.0
1   1    0.0 0.0
2   0   -9.0933087157900000E-5  0.0000000000000000E+00
2   1   -2.7220323615900000E-09 -7.5751829208300000E-10
2   2   3.4709851601400000E-5   1.6729490538300000E-08
3   0   -3.2035914003000000E-06 0.0000000000000000E+00
3   1   2.6327440121800000E-05  5.4643630898200000E-06
3   2   1.4188179329400000E-05  4.8920365004800000E-06
3   3   1.2286058944700000E-05  -1.7854480816400000E-06
4   0   3.1973095717200000E-06  0.0000000000000000E+00
4   1   -5.9966018301500000E-06 1.6619345194700000E-06
4   2   -7.0818069269700000E-06 -6.7836271726900000E-06
4   3   -1.3622983381300000E-06 -1.3443472287100000E-05
4   4   -6.0257787358300000E-06 3.9396371953800000E-06
```

I'm trying to write a function where an array is made using the numbers in the 3rd columns, taking their positions in the array from the first two columns, and the empty cells are 0s. For example:

```
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
-9.09330871579000e-05   -2.72203236159000e-09   3.47098516014000e-05    0
-3.20359140030000e-06   2.63274401218000e-05    1.41881793294000e-05    1.22860589447000e-05
```

At the same time, I'm also trying to make a second array but using the numbers from the 4th column not the 3rd. The code that I've written so far is as follows and this is the array produced, I'm not even sure where the 4.41278e-08 comes from:

```
import numpy as np
def createarray(filepath,maxdegree):
    Cnm = np.zeros((maxdegree+1,maxdegree+1))
    Snm = np.zeros((maxdegree+1,maxdegree+1))
    fid = np.genfromtxt(filepath)
    for row in fid:
        for n in range(0,maxdegree):
            for m in range(0,maxdegree):
                Cnm[n+1,m+1]=row[2]
                Snm[n+1,m+1]=row[3] 
    return [Cnm, Snm]

0   0   0   0
0   4.41278e-08 4.41278e-08 4.41278e-08
0   4.41278e-08 4.41278e-08 4.41278e-08
0   4.41278e-08 4.41278e-08 4.41278e-08
```

I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not getting the right array. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First, have you looked at `fid`?  does it look right?  You might even want to print (some of) it, for us to see.  If the problem is in the following processing, you should be able to debug it by examining the results iteration by iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the first set of numbers starting with 0 0 1.0 0.0 is a snippet from "fid".

Comment: Is it not a matter of `for row in fid: Cnm[int(row[0]), int(row[1])] = row[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data appear to be in a COO sparse matrix format already. This means, that you could use your own function, but you could also capitalize on the work done in the `scipy.sparse` package.

For example this code creates a function that would generate one of your matrices at a time. You could modify it to return both matrices.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

def createarray(filepath, maxdegree, value_column):
   """Create single array from file"""
    # load sparse data into numpy array
    data = np.loadtxt(filepath)

    # use coo_matrix to create the sparse matrix where the
    # values are found in the value_column column of data
    M = sparse.coo_matrix((data[:,value_column], (data[:,0], data[:,1])), shape=(maxdegree+1, maxdegree+1))
    
    # if you need a numpy array call toarray() otherwise you
    # can return M which is sparse and more memory efficient
    return M.toarray()
```

Then for the first matrix you wanted to create you would set `value_column` to 2, and for the second you would set `value_column` to 3.

```py
# first matrix
Cnm = createarray(filepath, maxdegree, 2)

# second matrix
Snm = createarray(filepath, maxdegree, 3)
```

Comment: When I try that I get the error "ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions"?

Comment: @Nmellor, are you sure that `maxdegree` is the largest value in either of the first two columns?

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to check that.

Comment: @Nmellor, with the correct value in `maxdegree`, is this working for you now then? If so, please accept this answer so others know this is resolved.